# package install problem !! minecraft_ros

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to install this package: minecraft-ros

But it fails :( showing me this error when i execute make:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/2schematic/build$ make
[ 33%] Built target rgbd2schematic
[ 66%] Built target octomap2schematic
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcd2schematic.dir/src/pcd_converter.cpp.o
/opt/ros/hydro/2schematic/src/pcd_converter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool rgbd_2_schematic::PcdConverter::convertData(rgbd_2_schematic::Schematic&)’:
/opt/ros/hydro/2schematic/src/pcd_converter.cpp:120:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘getMinMax3D(rgbd_2_schematic::PointCloudT&, rgbd_2_schematic::PointT&, rgbd_2_schematic::PointT&)’
/opt/ros/hydro/2schematic/src/pcd_converter.cpp:120:42: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:58:3: note: void pcl::getMinMax3D(const PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr&, int, int, int, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Vector4f&)
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:58:3: note:   candidate expects 6 arguments, 3 provided
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:76:3: note: void pcl::getMinMax3D(const PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr&, int, int, int, const string&, float, float, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Vector4f&, bool)
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:76:3: note:   candidate expects 10 arguments, 3 provided
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:143:3: note: template<class PointT> void pcl::getMinMax3D(const typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr&, const string&, float, float, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Vector4f&, bool)
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:160:3: note: template<class PointT> void pcl::getMinMax3D(const typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr&, const std::vector<int>&, const string&, float, float, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Vector4f&, bool)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd2schematic.dir/src/pcd_converter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd2schematic.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASE, I NEED HELP !!

thx in advance ..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133231/package-install-problem-!!-minecraft_ros/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-02-25**:
Where did you get this package?
It says: no matching function for call to ‘getMinMax3D..

And then it gives you some ideas to call the "getMinMax3D" right. If you want just change the code at pcd_converter.cpp:120:42 to fix this with one of the suggestions.

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2014-02-26**:
I get it from here: https://code.google.com/p/minecraft-ros/wiki/Install
I changed the code at pcd_converter as he said but it doesn't function.
Any other suggestion please !

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-02-27**:
This is strange..

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/group__common.html#ga3166f09aafd659f69dc75e63f5e10f81

https://github.com/idryanov/2schematic/blob/master/src/pcd_converter.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
The problem is that it is linking the wrong pcl library. pcd_converter is looking for getMinMax3D and it is looking in pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h. The function that takes a point cloud and two points is in pcl/common/common.h

to fix this problem edit include/pcd_converter.h and add:
#include <pcl/common/common.h>

then run cmake again and  it should build correctly

hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [jonathanbyrn](https://answers.ros.org/users/14241/jonathanbyrn/) with karma: 26 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1